# Java Spring MVC How to get this set value?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How to get the value has been set from GET method? How to pass the value to POST method? Should I declare global variable?

EDIT: What I want is doing something on GET method and display a textbox on jsp if setdisplayBox = true. When the user POST the form, the setdisplayBox should be true too and return the same jsp without redirect

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSuccess(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("user") User user, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String boxDisplay = "True"; 
    user.setdisplayBox(boxDisplay);
    return "success";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String resetPassword(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("user") User user, ModelMap modelMap) 
{
    user.setdisplayBox(user.getdisplayBox()); //how to get value has been set above?
    return "success";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a global variable for the user.

```
private User userAccount;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSuccess(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("user") User user, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String boxDisplay = "True"; 
    user.setdisplayBox(boxDisplay);
    userAccount = user; //load user in to global var 
    return "success";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String resetPassword(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("user") User user, ModelMap modelMap) 
{
    user.setdisplayBox(userAccount.getdisplayBox()); 
    userAccount = null; //reset it to something to make sure you are loading it to another user later.
    return "success";
}
```

Comment: Sry my code seems a bit confusing, I just edited. What I want is doing something on GET method and display a textbox on jsp file if setdisplayBox = true. When the user POST the form, the setdisplayBox should be true too and return the same jsp